# MYSQL - Where condition problem, trying to input data, but if the data did not exist only

Tags: php, mysql

execute this code but having problem at WHERE NOT Exist line, am i missing something?

```
INSERT INTO sop_records SET
                        uid = '$user_id',
                        season_id = '$season_id',
                        start_date = '$startDate',
                        rec_date_create = now(),
                        rec_sop_unique_id = '$unique_id',
                        status = '1' 
                        WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sop_records 
                        WHERE start_date = '$startDate' AND rec_sop_unique_id = '$unique_id' AND season_id = '$season_id' LIMIT 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

`SET` can only assign one variable at a time

`SELECT` can make multiple assignments at once.

so, remove `SET` and use `SELECT`

```
INSERT INTO sop_records SELECT
            uid = '$user_id',
            season_id = '$season_id',
            start_date = '$startDate',
            rec_date_create = now(),
            rec_sop_unique_id = '$unique_id',
            status = '1' 
            WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sop_records 
            WHERE start_date = '$startDate' AND rec_sop_unique_id = '$unique_id' AND season_id = '$season_id' LIMIT 1)
```

Comment: I just want to Set the data once in the database, and I do not want it to be duplicate data. I manage to run it but seem it not running like what I am intended.